# Sitecore Login using CLI Command /.well-known/openid-configuration: Bad Gatway

Tags: sitecore-cli

I have `Sitecore 10.1` instance in my machine. I would like to login into `Sitecore` using below **Sitecore CLI command** on the powershell window:

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://SC101identityserver.dev.local --cm https://sc101sc.dev.local/ --allow-write true
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error connecting to https://sc101identityserver.dev.local/.well-known/openid-configuration: Bad Gateway
```

[image]

My `Sitecore` instance is working fine and able to login into `Sitecore`.

Can someone help in fixing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I hit the below URL, it was giving HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure error.

`https://sc101identityserver.dev.local/.well-known/openid-configuration: Bad Gateway`

Later I found that license file at the identityserver website was not valid. So, I changed the license file at ***/sitecoreruntime/license.xml***. Again I checked the above URL and this time it was giving valid JSON response.

Now I try to login into Sitecore using `Sitecore CLI` command and able to see login popup and console error also got fixed.

Thanks.